# how to set up a server to run an application which is based on c language

Tags: java, php, c

I had a c based application , I want to test that application,
so initial step for testing is to create a server locally in my laptop.

My Question is how to set up a server locally in our laptop to run application which is based on c language.
(for applications written in php, java, and web based languages, we setup servers like apache tomcat, xampp, glassfish, etc., but i need for c based language)

how to set up and how to run my application?

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having problems with? Could you read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and update your question. Currently it is not clear what you are asking

Comment: How to setup a server locally in my laptop for running a c based application? @beresfordt

Comment: Read up on CGI programming. You can write a CGI program in just about any commonly used language.